# Arrow comes sligtly (about 1 px ) below the div boundry

Tags: html, css

I have  a code here for a nav bar. When I hover over the links, a small arrow which is a png image should display below it in the center. The below code works fine in Firefox and Chrome but in IE, the arrow goes slightly below the div so only a part of it is seen. What's the issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">


</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="logo-wrapper">
<a href="#"><img src="logo.png" id="logo"></a>

</div> 
<div id="menu-wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a id="home" href="#"  >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

below is the CSS:

```
body,html{
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

#wrapper{
    width:954px;
    height:59px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-left:15px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-style:none;
    outline:none;
    background-color:black;
    position:relative;

}

#logo{
padding:0px;
margin:none;
outline:none;
height:59px;

}
#logo-wrapper{
 width:223px;
 float:left;
 padding:0px;
 margin:none;
}

#menu-wrapper{
padding:0px;
margin:none;
position:absolute;
bottom:6%;
right:30px;
}

ul{
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    bottom:-5px;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:none;
}
li{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:inline;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;

}
#home{
margin:0px;
padding:none;
background: url('arrow.png') center 100% no-repeat;
}

#menu-wrapper a{

height:31px;
padding-bottom:16px;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:"arial";
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;
color:white;
margin-right:13px;
margin-bottom:0px;
border:none;
}
#menu-wrapper a:hover{
padding:none;
margin:0px;
outline:none;
border:none;
background: url('arrow.png') center 100% no-repeat;
}
#menu-wrapper a:active{
outline:none;
margin:0px;
border:none;
}
#menu-wrapper a:focus{
outline:none;
margin:0px;
border:none;
}
```

Comment: IE is an issue :D.. btw it's more welcome to put the code in http://jsfiddle.net too -> easier to see the problem and edit code

Comment: I made a Jsfiddle for people who need it :) http://jsfiddle.net/ZUrWw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add a z-index to the arrow image.

Like this:

```
#logo{
padding:0px;
margin:none;
outline:none;
height:59px;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Edit. `z-index` on all images inside `#logo-wrapper`

```
#menu-wrapper img{
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: arrow image is not the logo one. Its loaded as background-image in the  a:hover css section. How do I set z-index for this? I'm sorry I'm totally new to this.

Comment: No. I think you are not getting it. It's hard to explain without a visual cue. Anyways, The element Im concerned is inside the menu-wrapper not the logo-wrapper. Basicall,when I hover over the links. in menu-wrapper, I should have a small arrow display below the link. This is done using a:hover where i use background-image :url(arrow.png) on hover. Ive set some position for this and works fine too in firefox and Chrome but in IE, the arrow goes slightly below the parent div therefore making only a part of it appear and rest is clipped

Comment: I edited it just before your comment. I change #logo-wrapper to #menu-wrapper.

Comment: No it doesnt sorry I tried. Also there is no img tag inside menu-wrapper so I dont know how this will resolve it anyway. I think its more to do with how IE is rounding off padding and things . Because if I set padding-bottom to 15px in #menu-wrapper a , then It works fine in IE but not in chrome and firefox ( arrow goes a pixel up than its supposed to ) whearas if i keep it at 16 , it goes down a pixel in IE but remains where its supposed to in others .

Comment: Just try to edit your code a bit. change padding:none; to padding: 0; and remove the outline: none; and border:none; the're not needed.

Comment: Also try to add background-position: center center. and remove your center value from the background-image. just add it below the background-image code.

Comment: Yes I've done that. I've tried a lot of combinations and nothing seems to work :( only thing which fixes it is if I set #wrapper height to above 75px which ofcourse is not what I need in this layout.

Comment: Ive done as you said background-position: center center positions the arrow right below the text while I want it slightly below it and touching the parent div border. Setting it to background-position: center bottom has the same effect as I did before.

Comment: Ok. Without IE7 I can't see the problem so I can't help you sorry. I've tried something. but did not work.

Comment: Thanks for the help . I finally solved it. Setting the ul list to float instead of inline did the trick.